# Swift- Waiting for asynchronous for-in loop to complete before calling completion handler swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, grand-central-dispatch

I'm baffled as to what is the best way to achieve this. I am trying to keep a running total of Double values that I am looping through and adding together, via a network call. Everything I've read says to use DispatchGroup. My completion either calls too early or doesn't get called at all and I've tried every configuration of .enter, .leave, and .wait that I can think of.

```
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    var runningTotal: Double = 0.00

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let bills = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            //error
            return
        }

        for billId in bills.keys {
            group.enter()
            print("Entering")
            Database.database().reference().child("bills").child(billId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                guard let bill = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                    return
                }
                if let amount = bill["amount"] as? Double {
                    runningTotal += amount
                }
                group.leave()
                print("Leaving")
            })
        }
        completion(runningTotal)
    }
    group.wait()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Avoid ever calling `wait` from the main thread. The use cases for that are pretty limited. The `notify` is a much safer way to achieve the same thing.
2. Make sure you call `leave` from every path inside you’re loop. This can be achieved nicely with `defer` block.

So:

```
func foo(completion: @escaping (Double?) -> Void) {
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
        guard let bills = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            //error
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        let group = DispatchGroup()
        var runningTotal = 0.0

        for billId in bills.keys {
            group.enter()
            print("Entering")
            Database.database().reference().child("bills").child(billId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
                defer { group.leave() }
                guard let bill = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                    return
                }
                if let amount = bill["amount"] as? Double {
                    runningTotal += amount
                }
                print("Leaving")
            }
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            completion(runningTotal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I should mention that I do not want to return to the main thread directly after this call. Going directly to another network function after this is called.

Comment: But you _never_ want to block the main thread. You risk having the watchdog process kill your app and it’s a substandard UX at best. Just invoke your next network call in the completion handler of this call (or some pattern like that). Use asynchronous patterns to achieve the required dependencies rather than blocking the main thread.

Comment: Rob, it still seems as though the completion is being called right away: My print statement looks like Optional(0.0) , Entering, entering, entering... etc.

Comment: Sounds like your notify call is not inside the observeSingleEvent closure.

Comment: @Rob May I suggest moving the declaration of `group` and `runningTotal` to just before the `for` loop.

Comment: Rob if you wouldn't mind clarifying one thing for me; if I do not want to return to the main thread, should I even call notify at all?

Comment: @rmaddy - yep, that’s better (though won’t change the behavior). Done.

Comment: @chenders - I know it feels so logical and intuitive to just block the main thread and wait for this function to finish, but it’s just plain wrong. Honestly, we’ve all been there before we grokked asynchronous patterns, so I get why you want to do that, but it’s a serious mistake.

Comment: @Rob I don’t think we are on the same page unfortunately. I definitely do not want to block the main thread. Am I doing so? This function is on a background thread and I want to keep it that way. The next function I am calling with the completion handler is also on a background thread.

Comment: Ah, I read “I don’t want to return to the main thread” and thought you were saying that you were calling this from the main thread and didn’t want to return to it. If you’re saying that you are doing this from a background thread, then `wait` is not quite the disaster it is when you use it on the main thread. But it still begs the question as to why you want to block any thread at all when there are good patterns that avoid that. But, if you are definitely calling this from a background thread, then you _can_ use `wait` instead of `notify` and change this to not use completion handlers at all.

Comment: Ok, we are on the same page now I believe. wait() is a blocking call, I understand that now. I guess what I need to learn is the "patterns to avoid that" part. Only been developing for a year and a half so still learning a ton on the fly...

Comment: @Rob Got it figured out. Thank you for the help! My main issue was certainly trying to use .wait() instead of .notify and not understanding what it was doing. First time using DispatchGroup. About drove me crazy haha.

Answer (score 2):

You should wait until all group tasks are done, then call completion block.

Like below.

```
    var runningTotal: Double = 0.00

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let bills = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            //error
            return
        }

        let group = DispatchGroup()
        for billId in bills.keys {
            group.enter()
            print("Entering")
            Database.database().reference().child("bills").child(billId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                guard let bill = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                    group.leave()
                    return
                }
                if let amount = bill["amount"] as? Double {
                    runningTotal += amount
                }
                group.leave()
                print("Leaving")
            })
        }
        group.wait()
        completion(runningTotal)
    }
```

Comment: In trying that, the completion(runningTotal) returns immediately before even looping through once.